# CSS Circular Border On Scaled Rectangular Image

Tags: css

I have a 200x100 rectangular image, and I scaled it down to 50px while preserving its original aspect ratio by using

```
max-width: 50px;
max-height: 50px;
```

I would like to give it a circular picture effect so `border-radius: 50%` was used. However, this won't work and will give me an oval shape image as the image is not a perfect square. How would I approach this problem while preserving my original image aspect ratio? I am also ok with having white stripes around my image to fill in the gap and make it a square.

Thanks

Comment: You want to make your non-square rectangle into a perfect circle? You'll have to make it into a square first I believe. You can maintain your aspect ratio if you apply the border-radius to a wrapper element with a set width/height (that are the same dimension).

Comment: @Jasper How would I make it a square first? I dont want to clip certain part of image. Howevever, I dont mind having to fill in the empty gap around image with white background to make it a square.

Comment: If you're looking for a CSS only solution, the only way is to crop the image into a square and then apply 50% border radius. Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to create a (square) div element around the image, hide the actual image and use the image URL as the div background, for which the `background-size: cover` property can be applied.

Comment: If you are trying to make it into a thumbnail where you'll have a circular border and an image in between, you are better off with a circular border and the image as a background. It'll show whatever is possible to show in that circle, rest would just be cut off.

Comment: Also, are your images all the same aspect ratio (2:1) or is that variable?

Comment: @QuynhNguyen I would use a CSS background property to display the image then. You can set your element to be square, whatever dimensions, then set it's background image as the image you want to display and set `background-size` to `contain` for modern browsers and something like `100% auto` or `auto 100%` for old browsers (depending on whether you want full-width or full-height).

Comment: @Terry It's a variable and could be anything.

Comment: @QuynhNguyen If that's the case, a pure-CSS solution is very hard (or almost impossible). Would you consider a JS-based solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
.my-ele {
    background-color    : #000;
    background-image    : url([URL TO IMAGE]);
    background-repeat   : no-repeat;
    background-position : 50% 50%;
    background-size     : 100% auto;
    background-size     : contain;
    width               : 300px;
    height              : 300px;
    border-radius       : 50%;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ArURx/1/

I would use a CSS background property to display the image. You can set your element to be square, whatever dimensions, then set it's background image as the image you want to display and set `background-size` to `contain` for modern browsers and something like `100% auto` or `auto 100%` for old browsers (depending on whether you want full-width or full-height).

Comment: What if the image source came from img src tag and not background-image? Does the same effect you did above still achievable?

Comment: If you would want to convert the `<img src="">` into the `<div>` source, you will have to rely on JavaScript.

Comment: @Terry Actually, its the other way around. Jasper pretty much almost got it because I want that exact same effect using '<img src="">' and not having to set background-image

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you do not want to modify your markup (using `<img>` on the pages alone), and would want to dynamically create `<div>` elements for the purpose, then you will need to reply on JS to inject the image source as background image for your div.

Comment: @QuynhNguyen Using an `<img />` element, you can only make a circle if the element has equal height/width dimensions. That's the beauty of using a background image, you can clip the image as necessary.

Comment: Just a quick note, this solution works well and if you've searched and found this but want your image to fill the circle created use: background-size:auto 100%; and background-size:cover;